# ImportError: No module named 'pymysql'となりmysqlに接続できない

Tags: python

対処法を教えていただけませんでしょうか。環境はcentos7、python3.4.3です。

■error 
`ImportError: No module named 'pymysql`

■入力したコマンド 
`import pymysql`

■インストール方法

`pip install PyMySQL`

■`pip list`の結果

`PyMySQL (0.6.7)`

Answer (score 2):

【自己解決】
 `pip install PyMySQL`ではなく
`pip3 install PyMySQL`

でいけました。

Comment: false / true はどういう意味ですか？

Comment: false=誤、true=正という意味でしょうかね。wrong/rightの方が適切かも……